# how to deploy jersey production environment

Tags: jersey

I have to write a REST API server and choose Jersey as framework, while I have no idea about whether a web server is required for a production environment. And to use Jersey, which server suits best?

Comment: I have used Tomcat and IBM-WAS servers, same webapp deployed on both. Jersey+Jackson+OpenJPA application.

Comment: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#server-jdk - i would prefer jetty for stability over grizzly for customisability. both are embedded web servers - perfect match for cloud managed web-services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Grizzly in the past and found that there was some sort of race condition when trying to get very high throughput. This however is about 1-2 years ago, so it may or may not be fixed. Back then, comparing and switching to Jetty, this problem went away, and performance went up - so I would definitely try that.

For your problem, for easy and fast deployment, may I suggest dropwizard.

You can read up on DW here: http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/getting-started.html#jetty-for-http

Essentially, what this provides you with, is a framework that already integrates jersey, jackson and jetty for you. Essentially it leaves you with the responsibility of simply writing your resource code (for jersey) and register it. Dropwizard will take care of the rest for you.

Alternatively, you can set up your own embedded jetty (or run it through maven) for deployment. I would not recommend that from the start, but in case you are interested you will find plenty of results on google how to set up an embedded jetty with a jersey resource. It is not very hard, just some extra work that Dropwizard will do for you.

I hope that helps,
Artur